# Is there anyone successfully running a mail server in google cloud?

Tags: ssh, docker, google-cloud-platform

Mail servers cannot resolve to my SMTP mail server in google cloud. Can someone please help? Its a mailcow server

Comment: Nobody can help because you have provided absolutely no relevant details. Please edit your question.

Comment: Ok let me try again. I have setup a mail server which I have hosted in google cloud on a Linux vm with docker. I'm having issues with Port 25 being blocked and so the SMTP server is unreachable, so the server is not sending or receiving emails. I want to know if there is another way I could configure the server such that I can get around the SMTP server only being available thru port 25? I also asking if  there is anyone who is running their own mail servers hosted on GCP and maybe they can share their experience? Hope i'm beginning to make sense.

Comment: So what are the issues you are having?

Comment: Google already has an email service, that's probably why they are blocking yours.  try a different provider.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud [blocks SMTP port 25 egress](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail). This prevents traditional SMTP servers from functioning. You can use other ports such as 465/587 but that is typically used to login to a traditional SMTP server (Gmail, Workplace, O365, Zoho, etc) for email forwarding.

In summary, you cannot host a traditional email server in Google Cloud. You can implement email forwarders.